# Super basic code: Why is my loop not breaking?

Tags: c++, for-loop, break

```
for(int i=0;i<50;i++,size++)
{
    cin >> inputnum[i];
    cout << size;
    if(inputnum[i] == '.')
    {
        break;
    }
}
```

The break breaks the input stream but the size keeps outputting.

The output of size is `012345678910111213...474849`.

I tried putting size++ inside the loop but it made no difference.  And size afterwards will be equal to 50, which means it went through the full loop.

I forgot to explain that I added the cout << size within the loop to debug/check why it outputted to 50 after the loop even if I only inputted 3 numbers.

Comment: Please add some tags

Comment: @EdHeal A bunch of numbers for example test scores, but not all the way to 50.  And I'm trying to count the number of inputs while inputting.

Comment: You need to post an MCVE.

Comment: @juanchopanza I'm sorry I may be too beginner to post here, I have no idea what that is.

Comment: For the benefit of other readers as well as Jonathan: [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is local jargon for 'minimal, complete and verifiable example' here on Stack Exchange and hence it needs to be looked up in the [help section](http://stackoverflow.com/help). juanchopanza's arrogant, nonsensical remark should be voted down, but of course that's not possible here...

Comment: @DarthGizka Ah okay thanks for the help.  This is probably the first of many questions, just trying my best to learn haha.

Comment: LOL, it seems that my comment with the answer just got deleted with the reply under which I posted it (the responder probably chickened out and deleted the post because of the downvotes)... If no-one posts a correct answer then I will do it - for the benefit of later readers - once the dust settles.

Comment: clearly, `inputnum[i]` never was equal to `'.'`.  To see why it isn't, inspect the value in your debugger, or add a line that outputs the character code of `inputnum[i]`.  Also it would be good to check whether input failed.

Comment: @DarthGizka: Typing "mcve stackoverflow" into Google is not too much to ask from a programmer.

Comment: Please stop LOLing and provide the MCVE already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that `inputnum` is an array of `int` (or some other numeric type). When you try to input `'.'`, nothing actually goes into  `inputnum[i]` - the `cin >> inputnum[i]` expression actually fails and puts `cin` into a failed state.

So, `inputnum[i]` is not changed when inputting a `'.'` character, and the `break` never gets executed.

Here's an slightly modified version of your code in a small, complete program that demonstrates using `!cin.good()` to break out of the input loop:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int inputnum[50];
    int size = 0;

    for(int i=0;i<50;i++,size++)
    {
        cin >> inputnum[i];
        if (!cin.good()) {
            break;
        }
    }

    cout << "size is " << size << endl;    
    cout << "And the results are:" << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        cout << "inputnum[" << i << "] == " << inputnum[i] << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This program will collect input into the `inputnum[]` array until it hits EOF or an invalid input.

Comment: Wow ok makes sense, how would i break an integer array for loop while inputting?

Comment: I just set the break command to 00, but I'm not sure that's the best way.

Comment: Perhaps break if `!cin.good()` immediately after reading from `cin`? Personally, I'm not a fan of performing formatted input directly into a non-string variable - I prefer to read a line into a string then have something which can handle errors parse that string.  However, if you can live with very simple (or non-existant) error handling, such as in example code, simple utilities, or test programs, formatted input directly into non-string variables is fine.

Comment: You are wrong. `inputnum[i]` will equal `'.'` if and when the number 46 is entered. That's not what the OP intended but your statement is still wrong.

Comment: @DarthGizka - I believe that the problem the question is about is that the OP is inputting the character '.' to indicate that input is finished.  That results in `cin >> inputnum[i]` failing and putting `cin` in a failed state.  You are correct that inputting 46 would cause the `break` to be executed in the OP's code snippet, but that's not the problem he describes in the question (though it is a problem that needs to be fixed in his program).

Comment: Interesting 46 does work.  But what would happen if I need to use 46 in my data input...

Comment: @Michael Burr: You are right, but amending the wrong statement (or removing it, as you have now done) was still necessary. Answers must be held to a higher standard than questions... Thanks for improving your answer (so I don't need to post one myself); my downvote has been withdrawn and reversed.

Comment: Tried it @MichaelBurr probably my favorite answer so far.  I will probably go with this thank you.  I can ask the user to input a letter to break out of the loop.  My original '.' would have been my preferred way but oh well.  Thanks for tolerating my stupid questions everyone!

Comment: @JonathanPan: you can still use '.' to terminate the loop.

Comment: I tried @DarthGizka but I'm not even allowed to until I have enough "reputation"... Michael Burr That is true haha.

Comment: @Jonathan: you can accept the answer, though, by clicking on the check mark... (which will also boost your own reputation a bit <g>)

Answer (score -2):

What is `inputnum` ? Make sure t's a `char[]`!! with clang++ this compiles and works perfectly:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  int size = 0;
  char inputnum[60];
  for(int i=0;i<50;i++,size++) {
    std::cin >> inputnum[i];
    std::cout << size;
    if(inputnum[i] == '.')  {
      break;
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

(in my case with the following output:)

```
a
0a
1s
2d
3f
4g
5.
6Argento:Desktop marinos$
```

Your code seams OK as long as you're testing `char` against `char` in your loop and not something else.. Could it be that `inputnum` is some integral value ? if so, then your test clause will always evaluate to false unless `inputnum` matches the numerical value `'.'` is implicitly casted to..

**EDIT**

Apparently you are indeed trying to put `char` in a `int[]`. Try the following:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  using namespace std;
  int size = 0;
  int inputnum[50];
  char inputchar[50];
  for(int i=0;i<50;i++,size++) {
    cin >> inputchar[i];
    inputnum[i] = static_cast<int>(inputchar[i]); // or inputnum[i] = (int)inputchar[i];
    cout << size << endl; // add a new line in the end
    if(inputchar[i] == '.')  break;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Then again this is probably a lab assignment, in a real program I'd never code like this. Tat would depend on the requirements but I'd rather prefer using STL containers and algorithms or stringstreams. And if forced to work at a lower-level C-style, I'd try to figure out to what number '.' translates to (simply by int a = '.'; cout << a;`) and put that number directly in the test clause. Such code however might be simple but is also **BAD** in my opinion, it's unsafe, implementation specific and not really C++.

Comment: I am trying to input double or triple digit integers and my lab assignment asks for integer arrays.  I'm probably confused with the '.' because it breaks out of char loops perfectly.  However in this case it's stopping the input but it's still outputting.

Comment: in that case I'd suggest you put the input in some `char[]` buffer first and then convert it to integer correctly (maybe using something like `boost::lexical_cast`) so that you know exactly what your casts will result to. Then you may put the result inside your `int[]`array but use the `char[]` buffer in your test clause.

Comment: I just set the break command to 00, but I'm not sure that's the best way. @Marinos K Sorry I don't know how to do that haha, im only in my 2nd coding class.  Might be too beginner for this website.

Comment: it's not.. the best way is to make sure your not testing apples against or oranges.. Just do the conversion from `char` to `int` yourself - that's it. In the end of the day your program would not behave correctly otherwise. What do you expect it to do with input such as `marinos` or `abcdef` ?? This is valid input the way you've written it..

Comment: Ok that's something I can understand thank you!  I will try this, is this the simplest way to break a loop while inputting into an integer array?

Comment: @JonathanPan define **simple**.. this is probably a lab assignment, in a real program I'd never like code like this.. What code I'd write would depend on the requirements, but I'd rather prefer using STL containers and algorithms or stringstreams, etc. In a lower-evel C-style and machine-oriented kind of code, I'd try to figure out what number `'.'` translates to (simply by `int a = '.'; `cout << a;`) and put that number directly in the test clause. Such code however maybe be simple but is also **BAD** in my opinion, it's unsafe, implementation specific and not C++-style

Comment: Ah I see.  I'm just trying to learn the basics at the moment.  Thanks for all your help and I will upvote!

Comment: @Marinos: do you expect the user of your code to memorise the ACII table so that they know to enter '.' for 46? What about control codes? Entering 26 would require ^Z but `cin` interprets it as EOF...

Comment: the code in the edit probably doesn't do anything useful  . the static_cast is redundant and it won't handle multi-digit numbers

Comment: @DarthGizka I wrote in the code above that "Such code however maybe be simple but is also BAD in my opinion, it's unsafe, implementation specific and not C++-style " and added that in real-life applications I'd got for a completely different strategy depending on the requirements.

Comment: @M.M the static_cast is not redundant IMO, it makes it explicit that some kind of cast is involved. Then again the code is not carved-in stone, the original question is about the break loop, not about how to convert multi-digit chars into integers..